# Can you manually allocate virtual pages in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, operating-system

I'm playing with a simple cache simulator I wrote, and I want to know if it's possible to allocate a virtual page manually through Linux so I can test way conflicts.

I understand this is doubtful and probably not something even considered in Linux's design, and it is clearly easier to test this in a different manner (just passing a value for the address), but I just thought I'd throw this question out for my own curiosity.

I would have something like:

```
char *p1 = (char *)SomeLiteral;
*p1 = value1;
dcache.writeback(p1);

char *p2 = (char *)ADifferentLiteral;
*p2 = value2;
//may map to same set index and be brought to second way
dcache.writeback(p2);
```

This would probably work on some embedded systems, but it's obviously going to page fault under Linux. So, is there a way to allocate a virtual page for p1 and p2? Or even set the virtual address for a program's heap?

I apologize if this sounds obtuse, and thanks!

Comment: Learn about [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  How would that help him?  It seems that what he wants is to avoid pagefaults, and the way to do that is to touch each page in order to force allocation of physical memory to the virtual pages.

Comment: See also [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) & [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html)

Comment: If you mmap() a file, and there is not too much memory pressure (you have free memory available), the contents are stored in a kernel data structure called page cache, and will not hit the actual media (until munmap() or msync()). You can mmap() a file several times, obtaining new virtual addresses to essentially the same physical RAM. Use `MAP_NORESERVE` mmap() flag to avoid reserving swap for the mappings. You can use mlock() to ensure the pages stay in RAM (page cache), or madvise() to request that (no guarantees, just intent) or request their eviction. Use msync() to update file contents.

Answer (score 0):

If your system supports it, you can allocate single 1GB huge page then mlock() it so it won't be swapped out.

This page should be large enough that your experiments can all fit inside of it easily, but you'll need to know the cache hashing/placement algorithm to be sure.

Also, you won't know the most significant bits of the physical address of the page, and that leads me to another point - you may need to consider what inputs the cache placement algorithm takes on your system - indexing and tagging can each be done by physical or virtual addresses,  you should review your system's architecture to see how or if this impacts your research.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to allocate physical pages then just go through and touch each of the pages by writing a single value to it.  Say you need 1024 4k pages preallocated, then call malloc, then walk the addresses in 4k steps and write a single value at each of those addresses.

Comment: This alone may not keep the pages resident.